# Expected number of left-to-right maxima within a sequence of integers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, expected-value

The integers $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ are rearranged uniformly at random.
The position $k^\text{th}$ of the sequence is said to be a left-to-right maximum if all $k-1$ preceding integers is less than that of $k^\text{th}$ position. By convention, we also consider the first position to a left-to-right maximum as well.

I was asked to find the expected number of left-to-right maxima within the sequence of which the next position is also a left-to-right maxima; that is, the total number of integer $k<n$ such that the  $k^\text{th}$ and $(k+1)^\text{th}$ positions of the sequence are left-to-right maxima.

I tried to work up from $n=3,4,\ldots$ but couldn't form an induction hypothesis for arbitrary $n$.
Here's my attempt:

Let $N$ counts the total number of the left-to-right maximum at $k^\text{th}$ such that $(k+1)^\text{th}$ is also a left-to-right maximum.

1. The case when $n=3$.
   The possible outcomes with $N=1$ are when the sequence is of the form $(*,3,*)$, we have the total of $2$ possibilities. For $N=2$, the only possible outcome is $(1,2,3)$.
   So we can compute:
   $$
   E[N] = 1\cdot\frac{2}{3!}+2\cdot\frac{1}{3!} = \frac{4}{3!}.
   $$
2. The case when $n=4$.
   For $N=1$, we have $(*,4,*,*)$ and $(2,1,3,4)$ which has total of $3!+1$ outcomes.
   For $N=2$, we have $(2,3,4,1)$, $(1,3,4,2)$, $(1,2,4,3)$, a total of $\binom{3}{2}=3$. And finally, $N=3$, we have only $(1,2,3,4)$. From this we compute:
   $$
   E[N] = 1\cdot\frac{3!+1}{4!}+2\cdot\frac{3}{4!}+3\cdot\frac{1}{4!} = \frac{16}{4!} = \frac{4}{3!}.
   $$
3. The case when $n=5$.
   For $N=1$, we have $(*,5,*,*,*)$: $4!$ outcomes; $(*,*,*,5,*)$: $3\cdot\binom{4}{3}$ outcomes; and $(*,*,*,*,5)$: $2+2\cdot\binom{3}{2}$ outcomes; $44$ in total.
   For $N=2$, we have $(*,*,5,*,*)$: $2\cdot\binom{4}{2}$ outcomes; $(*,*,*,*,5)$: $3+2+1$ outcomes; $18$ in total.
   And finally, we have $4$ outcomes for $N=3$ and $1$ for $N=4$.
   From this we compute
   $$
   E[N] = 1\cdot\frac{44}{5!} + 2\cdot\frac{18}{5!} + 3\cdot\frac{4}{5!} + 4\cdot\frac{1}{5!} = \frac{96}{5!}.
   $$

However, this doesn't seem to go anywhere near the solution.
Is there any easier way to approach this?

Comment: What does it mean to "draw randomly from a set of all permutations"?  Is $X_i$ a permutation?   Or do you just mean that each $X_i\in \{1, \cdots, N\}$?  Are we choosing with replacement or without?

Comment: If the $X_i$ are numbers and we are choosing without replacement, then the probability that the $k^{th}$ selection is the largest amongst the first $k$ is $\frac 1k$.  that's all you need (in this particular case).

Comment: Oh, is $n$ the same as $N$?  That wasn't clear to me.  Maybe you are saying that we select a permutation (uniformly at random) from all the $N!$ permutations of $\{1, \cdots, N\}$.  In any event, please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a permutation of $(1,\ldots,n)$. I'll edit the post. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: No problem. Given the clarification, my prior hint is directly relevant.  (Note that the hint would equally apply to the case where you chose some, but not necessarily all, of the available digits.  So long as you always choose without replacement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the $k$-th entry of the random permutation is a left-to-right maximum is $\frac{1}{k}$. This will be independent of where the previous left-to-right maximum is located. So the probability of positions $k$ and $k+1$ both having left-to-right maxima is $\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$ (for $k=1,2,...,n-1$).

Hence by linearity of expectation, the expected value of the number of two consecutive left-to-right maxima is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$$ This sum telescopes, giving a value of $1-\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Wow, that looks super clean. I should have considered the probability of each adjacent pair being both left-to-right maxima. Thank you!